# exporting unique rows using row id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse

I have a huge table with duplicates of 500 GB and with partitions, have almost 2 billion records.

I am planning to write a condition where if 3 column values matches then pick those records, (say we got 4 duplicate records). And take export one of the record with min/max row id.

I know there may be different methods, like deletes or creating new table xyz. But We decided to approach using query option in export. So please help me if any one can get me a correct syntax.

I have been trying with:

```
query= schema.table:"WHERE ROWID <> 
(SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM schema.table A WHERE A.col1 = A.col1 AND A.col2 = A.col2 AND A.col3 = A.col3)"
```

But this will probably take duplicates, i tried with just = and <= sign and thats not helping me out. Its not exporting any rows, says exporting 0rows
So any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to get the minimum for each group; this will only require a single table scan (i.e. no correlated sub-queries).

```
SELECT a,b,c -- ,d,e,f,g ...
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROWID AS rid,
         MIN( ROWID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY a, b, c ) AS min_rid
  FROM   schema_name.table_name t
)
WHERE  rid = min_rid;
```

Answer (score 1):

use having and group by your dublicate columns

```
select a,b,c, count(*), min(rowid), max(rowid)
  from your_table
 group by a,b,c
 having count(*) > 1
```

then u can select needed rows like this

```
select * 
  from your_table 
 where rowid in (
    select min(rowid)--, max(rowid)
      from your_table
     group by a,b,c
     having count(*) > 1
)
```

sorry, if you need all rows inlude uniq and 1 of row what dublicate, no need having

```
select * 
      from your_table 
     where rowid in (
        select min(rowid)--, max(rowid)
          from your_table
         group by a,b,c
    )
```

Comment: Attention, this will not export the unique rows, but those which have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXIST operator to pick only one record from the table with the highest ROWID:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table B
  WHERE A.col1 = B.col1 AND A.col2 = B.col2 AND A.col3 = B.col3
    AND A.ROWID < B.ROWID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one... really appreciate the fast response.. i guess i had tried similar logics..dnt remember but will try surely.. on the subpartition level and check..

but my quick question to every one what you guyies have specified,  will this work out in export parameter in query block ?